# (C++) Add int and/or double and display sum

Tags: c++, class, sum

So I have just completed "Sum of two numbers" on SPOJ. My code passed the test cases; however, it doesn't seem very elegant to me. My first approach was to try implementing a template to handle multiple data types. I could not figure out how to successfully do this.

My question: How could this program be written so that it makes use of a class as well as a function template (which handles int and double). I feel that using floor() is a bit weird, inappropriate. If using a template is not a good solution then a better one would be nice to see as well. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:**
The solution below works just fine. I am very interested in learning more about classes (OOP is new to me) and I would also like to learn more about templates. Here is a link to the problem on SPOJ: http://www.spoj.com/problems/CHITEST1/

My code:

```
//For t test cases, output the sum of two numbers

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        double a, b, sum;
        cin >> a >> b;
        sum = a + b;
        if (sum != floor(sum)) cout << sum << endl;
        else cout << static_cast<int>(sum) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what you consider "elegant".

Comment: Why the type juggling ? Could you add a link to the complete problem statement ?

Comment: It would be nice if you elaborated on what you tried that didn't work, regarding implementing a templated solution. Did your solution try to account for `a` and `b` to be different types or the same?

Comment: I edited the original question.

Comment: What's wrong with `cin >> a >> b; cout << a + b << endl;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd say that applying !=/= to floating-point types is very dangerous. Even if you're using floor. Use comparisons to some very low epsilon value. (`if (abs(a - b) < eps)`, where epsilon is something like 0.00001, depending on your desired precision).

Second, I don't really understand the idea of floor being here, because noshowpoint cout modifier is enabled by default, which means, 3.3 + 4.7 *should* print exactly 8, if it calculated without any errors - not 8.00000(I wouldn't rely on that, because it can result in 7.99999998 or 8.00000001 as well). Floor has the same level of reliability, because floor(7.999998) is 7, not 8. To be honest, I'd use round here.

Third, if you want to learn OOP or templates, these are not the tasks you want to do. This site looks like too much of a contest-related, and you're in need of educational info. Look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: This question seems absolutely silly now. I had no idea that cout would handle this for me. Thanks for all of the help. I shall leave the variables as type double and just let cout determine whether it should display a decimal or not. Thanks for the guidance. I am using SPOJ as a way of practicing basic programming and I was just trying to force the use of OOP into the problem (something that is not needed at all).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void getAddAndPrint()
{
    T a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    T sum = a + b;
    cout << sum << endl;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    getAddAndPrint<double>();
    getAddAndPrint<int>();
    return 0;
}
```